# How to repeat collision in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a bird and a flower if the bird collides with the flower, the flower Destroys and another flower grows, else the flower drops and the bird goes away.

The problem is the newly created flower doesn't collide with the bird and just drops. how can I solve this?

```
public SpriteRenderer bird;
public SpriteRenderer flower;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("bird"))
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        float x = Random.Range(-8f, 8f);
        Instantiate(flower, new Vector3(x, 6, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("flower"))
    {
        Destroy(bird);
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure your flower prefab has the collider component on it i.e BoxCollider,MeshCollider,CapsuleCollider whatever you are using

Comment: I use circleCollider so it works. But the problem is it works only one time..

Comment: I'm clonning stack overflow This comment is for test

Answer (score 3):

You're instantiating the flower using Spriterenderer instead of a GameObject. Try changing `public SpriteRenderer flower;` to `public GameObject flower;` and create a prefab out of the flower Object.

If you don't know how to create a prefab, all you need to do is drag a GameObject from your scene to an assets map. If this is still unclear to you, here is a reference to the Unity documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingPrefabs.html

Once you've created the prefab you can drag the prefab onto the script into the flower GameObject. Then it should work.

If you have more questions make sure to ask them!